# How to change the recognized speech output in XML?

Tags: .net, xml, grammar, speech-recognition

I have defined multiple rules in XML for C#. The file is loaded and RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple) is eventually called for what I hope to become continuous recognition. The SpeechRecognized event correctly returns the recognized text from the grammar file.

Now, I wish to have a rule that accepts "ratio of two to three", but returns as displayed text "ratio of 2:3". I defined the following rule which works well to return "ratio of 2:3:" :

```
<rule id="ratio" scope="public">
<example>ratio of 2 to 3</example>
ratio of
<ruleref uri="#numbers"/><tag>$.value1=$$; </tag>
<item> to </item>
<ruleref uri="#numbers"/><tag>$.value2=$$;</tag>
<tag>$="ratio of "+ $.value1+ ":" +$.value2;</tag>
</rule>
```

But as this is a very most bottom rule, with multiple rules which call it, the only way I have found to echo the "2:3" to higher rules is by each of the higher rules also using the semantic interpreation. This would imply a fair amount of additional coding to rules that otherwise do not need semantics.

So, is there anyway within the XML rule "ratio" to have it return "ratio 2:3" without using semantics? Or more to the point, is there anyway within XML to specify the recognzied word "to" in "ratio of two to three" is actually ":"? Or for  that matter, how can the display be changed from "to" to "two" or "to" or "too" or ":"?

Thanks for any suggestions.